# MentaBean: Using OR instead of AND to load a list of beans

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mybatis, ebean

I am loading a list of male users belonging to city 235. Ok, that's easy. But now how do I load a list of male users belonging to city 235 or 236?

```
BeanManager beanManager = new BeanManager();
User userProps = PropertiesProxy.create(User.class);
BeanConfig userConfig = new BeanConfig(User.class, "Users")
   .pk(userProps.getId(), DBTypes.AUTOINCREMENT)
   .field(userProps.getUsername(), DBTypes.STRING)
   .field(userProps.getGender(), DBTypes.ENUMID.from(Gender.class))
   .field(userProps.getCity().getId(), "city_id", DBTypes.INTEGER);
beanManager.addBeanConfig(userConfig);

BeanSession session = new MySQLBeanSession(beanManager, conn);
User u = new User();
u.setGender(Gender.MALE);
u.setCity(new City(235));

List<User> users = session.loadList(u, lim(250));

System.out.println("Found: " + users.size());
```

But now I want to add an OR condition to my where clause! How do I do that?

I am using [this framework](http://mentabean.soliveirajr.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With any ORM, eventually you will have to write your queries. Like a query with group by, subqueries, left joins, etc. there is no way of doing what you want without SQL. Refer to [JOINS](http://mentabean.soliveirajr.com/mtw/Page/TableJoins/en/mentabean-table-joins) for an example. Below it is how you would do your query:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
ResultSet rset = null;

try {

    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder(1024);
    sql.append("select ");
    sql.append(session.buildSelect(User.class));
    sql.append(" from Users");
    sql.append(" where gender = ? and (city_id = ? or city_id = ?)");

    stmt = prepare(conn, sql.toString(), Gender.MALE.getId(), 235, 236); // varargs for params (from SQLUtils)

    rset = stmt.executeQuery();

    List<User> users = new LinkedList<User>();

    while(rset.next()) {
        User u = new User();
        session.populateBean(rset, u);
        users.add(u);
    }

    System.out.println("Number of users loaded: " + users.size());

} finally {
    close(rset, stmt, conn); // from SQLUtils
}
```

Note: You are missing the mapping for the gender column in your code, so I am assuming it is a [ENUMID](http://mentabean.soliveirajr.com/mtw/Page/Mapping/en/mentabean-mapping) and that the Gender enum has a getId() method. Otherwise, if you are using ENUMVALUE, change `Gender.MALE.getId()` to `Gender.MALE.toString()`.

Comment: I am using ENUMID. I edited to add the missing column. Thanks!